# Running scala script with line breaks in spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, spark-shell, scala-script

I'm trying to run a scala script through spark shell using the following command:
`spark-shell -i myScriptFile.scala`

I can get the above command to work when I have single-line commands, but if I have any line-breaks in the script (for readability), the spark-shell (or REPL?) interprets each of the lines as a full action. Here is a sample of my script:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import java.util.Calendar
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

// *********************** This is for Dev *********************** 
val dataRootPath = "/dev/test_data"
// *********************** End of DEV specific paths ***************

val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val currentDate = format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()).toString

val cc_df = spark.read.parquet(s"${dataRootPath}/cc_txns")
    .filter($"TXN_DT" >= date_sub(lit(current_date), 365) && $"TXN_DT" < lit(current_date))
    .filter($"AMT" >= 0)

....

System.exit(0)
```

When running the spark-shell with this script, I get the following error:

`<console>:1: error: illegal start of definition`

The syntax for the script is correct because if I start the shell and manually paste this code in with `:paste`, everything works fine.

I have tried ending all multi-line commands with a backslash `\` but that didn't work either.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can keep my script multi-lined but still be able to pass it the spark-shell as an argument to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
val x = {  some statement ... 
         . some statement2 ... 
         . idem ditto 
         . ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `:paste` then paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>). After pasting, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in the shell.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but I needed to run a script file (I also called this out in my original question as well!)